# Fedora 3 Disable Address Randomization

Tags: aslr

I want to disable address space layout randomization on my Fedora 3 virtual machine. I tried to go to /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space. Unlike normal Linux machine, such a file doesn't exist on Fedora 3. How do I disable ASLR for Fedora 3? Is the conf file located at somewhere else?